# Create directory

Tags: c#, directory

I need to create a directory, but, the directory when I need to create is inside of another directory. Something like this:

```
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"teste\teste\teste\teste\");
```

basically, this directory does not exist ( of course ), but, the `CreateDirectory(...)` not support this string style, how I can make to create this directories ?

My way to make this is that:

```
    private void createdir(string _path)
    {
        string path = string.Empty;
        string[] dir = _path.Split('\\');

        for(int i=0;i<dir.Length;i++)
        {
            path += dir[i] + "\\";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
    }
```

But, I want to know, if have a more better way to make this ( a more legible ) more rapid.

Comment: That first string works fine for me... What goes wrong when you use it?

Comment: Does none of this answers didn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Directory.Create("c:\teste\teste\teste\teste");` should workt

Answer (score 2):

according to MSDN, you can nest the directory . [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory("Public\\Html");
     Directory.CreateDirectory("\\Users\\User1\\Public\\Html");
     Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\Users\\User1\\Public\\Html"); // using verbatim string you can escape slashes


if(System.IO.Directory.Exists(yourPath))
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory(yourPath);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Directory.CreateDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can be used to create directories and subdirectories as specified by the path.

Here’s an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\ParentDir\ChildDir\SubChildDir\");
        Console.WriteLine("Directories Created");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/02/create-nested-directories-in-c-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

My chosen method would be:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"teste\teste\teste\teste\");
di.Create();
```

Comment: Edited as the `di.Exists` check is not needed. `Create()` does nothing if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is too complicated for this process. You don't have to use `Split()` method also to create this kind of directories.

You can use it like;

```
string tempFolderAbsolutePath = @"C:\Temp";
string subFolderRelativePath = @"teste\teste\teste\teste\";

DirectoryInfo tempFolder = new DirectoryInfo( tempFolderAbsolutePath );
DirectoryInfo subFolder = tempFolder.CreateSubdirectory( subFolderRelativePath );
```

As you can see, this process creates nested subdirectories.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your current directory is (say `C:\`) and you want to create a directory as `C:\A\B\C`, then I think the best way is using

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\A\B\C");
```

If you need a directory in *another root* (say, `D:\`) then you need to give the full path as

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\A\B\C");
```

You *`do not need to have a for loop`* to create each directory as CreateDirectory does it for you.